# R iteration optimisation

Tags: r

Hi I am new to R and wanting some help with optimising code.

I have a dataframe i want to set a bool value if there is a change to a value from its previous row.

The sample below seems to work, but is there a better/ more readable way to write this code?

Perhaps it is because i am new to R, but I find the df[,] syntax a bit hard to understand.

```
# df is a dataframe with a c, which contains an integer value

df$changed = FALSE
c = 0
for ( i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (df[i,]$c != c){
    c = df[i,]$c
    df[i,]$changed = TRUE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a vectorized way in multiple ways

**1)** base R

```
df$changed <- with(df, c(FALSE, c[-1] != c[-length(c)]))
```

Or with `diff`, if it is numeric

```
with(df, c(FALSE, diff(c) != 0))
```

---

**2)** with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(changed = c(FALSE, diff(c) != 0))
```

Or if it is not numeric

```
df %>%
   mutate(changed = c(FALSE, c[-1] != c[-n()]))
```

---

**3)** with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, changed := c(FALSE, diff(c) != 0)]
```

Or

```
setDT(df)[, changed := c(FALSE, c[-1] != c[-.N])]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(c = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in multiple ways :

Base R way :

```
df$changed <- c(FALSE, tail(df$c, -1) != head(df$c, -1))
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(changed = y != lag(y, default = first(y)))
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, changed := c != shift(c, fill = first(c))]
```